# HADOOP HIVE mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:execute(276)) - Execution failed with exit status: 137

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, emr, elastic-map-reduce

Im trying to run a job in hive with cluster(1 master, 4 core nodes[11.25GB each]) in AWS EMR, im joining(MAP joining) two tables one with 0.3 million entries(~11mb) and another table with almost 7 million entries(took care that big table should be last). Since, it is map join, first small table is getting hashed in distributed cache, after hashing some entries iam getting this error.

```
2015-10-07 11:21:35 Processing rows:    10600000    Hashtable size: 10599999    Memory usage:   5465925664  percentage: 0.143
2015-10-07 11:22:09 Processing rows:    10700000    Hashtable size: 10699999    Memory usage:   6078125280  percentage: 0.159
2015-10-07 11:22:42 Processing rows:    10800000    Hashtable size: 10799999    Memory usage:   2698310976  percentage: 0.071
2015-10-07 11:23:16 Processing rows:    10900000    Hashtable size: 10899999    Memory usage:   3272893216  percentage: 0.086
2015-10-07 11:23:49 Processing rows:    11000000    Hashtable size: 10999999    Memory usage:   3821330720  percentage: 0.10
2015-10-07 11:24:23 Processing rows:    11100000    Hashtable size: 11099999    Memory usage:   4398775280  percentage: 0.115
2015-10-07 11:24:57 Processing rows:    11200000    Hashtable size: 11199999    Memory usage:   5020884784  percentage: 0.132
2015-10-07 11:25:30 Processing rows:    11300000    Hashtable size: 11299999    Memory usage:   5608609488  percentage: 0.147
2015-10-07 11:26:04 Processing rows:    11400000    Hashtable size: 11399999    Memory usage:   6146767072  percentage: 0.161
2015-10-07 11:26:38 Processing rows:    11500000    Hashtable size: 11499999    Memory usage:   2622476744  percentage: 0.069
2015-10-07 11:27:11 Processing rows:    11600000    Hashtable size: 11599999    Memory usage:   3224517304  percentage: 0.084
2015-10-07 11:27:44 Processing rows:    11700000    Hashtable size: 11699999    Memory usage:   3793226384  percentage: 0.099
Execution failed with exit status: 137
Obtaining error information

Task failed!
Task ID:
Stage-4

Logs:

/mnt/var/log/apps/hive.log
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 137 from        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
```

Comment: Look up the associated job and examine the failed task(s).

Comment: thnks problem was solved.. reduced the number of mappers and increase memory for mapper @ChristopherB